# Select MAX from each week number

Tags: mysql

I have a table that is a football schedule, and each game has a gameID, and a week number (weekNum). I need to get the max gameID from each week (essentially getting the last game for each week).

Right now I am using this:

```
SELECT * FROM nflp_schedule WHERE gameID = (SELECT MAX(gameID) from nflp_schedule)
```

It pulls the very last game... but I have no clue how to pull the last game for each week. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would give you all weeks with maximum `gameID` for each. Rows returned would be ordered by `weekNum` in an ascending fashion.

```
SELECT weekNum, MAX(gameID) AS lastGameOfWeek
FROM nflp_schedule
GROUP BY weekNum
ORDER BY weekNum ASC
```

To get other values based on the returned gameID's derived above, you would need to either do a subselect as filtering condition or a join.

That could look like this (using subselect):

```
SELECT gameID, weekNum, homeScore, visitorScore
FROM nflp_schedule
WHERE gameID IN (
    SELECT MAX(gameID)
    FROM nflp_schedule
    GROUP BY weekNum
)
ORDER BY weekNum ASC
```

Or like this (using join):

```
SELECT
    n.gameID AS gameID,
    n.weekNum AS weekNum,
    n.homeScore AS homeScore,
    n.visitorScore AS visitorScore
FROM nflp_schedule AS n
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(gameID) AS maxGameID
    FROM nflp_schedule
    GROUP BY weekNum
) AS max
  ON n.gameID = max.maxGameID
ORDER BY n.weekNum ASC
```

You will note that the subselect used in the join query above looks very similar to the subselect that is used directly in WHERE clause in the example before this.  This is really just a way of applying the "table" created by the subselect as a filter on the main table.  You might want to test both approaches to see which executes faster given your data.

Comment: Any way to add the other values in the table? I want it to pull the visitorScore and homeScore for those respective gameID's... I added those in but it seems to just be pulling random values.

Comment: @enjoimark Not with using aggregate (i.e `MAX()`) functions.  If you just add other columns without specifying an aggregation, than you will get unpredictable values from any of the records in that group.  I will update my answer with a different approach you need to take in order to get values from the specific records that are returned from this query.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you. I am alright in MySQL but I've never had to run any "advanced" queries like this. I have learned something new today, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. I'm not on mysql so can't test, but this should do it ..

```
  select *
    from nflp_schedule a,
        ( SELECT weekNum, Max(gameID)
            FROM nflp_schedule
           ) b
   where a.gameID = b.gameID
```